# Is there a way to summon a large area of chickens in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Basically is there a way to do this `fill 0 4 0 5 4 5 minecraft:chicken` but with valid Minecraft syntax?

And perhaps if some blocks were occupied by armour stands, prevent the chickens from spawning where the armour stands are.

Comment: I have made a system similar to what you want long ago, but with 1.8 commands. It was also very laggy. But I just had another crazy idea: Spawners! Would it be allowed to change the blocks in that area?

Answer (score -1):

The `/fill` command only accepts blocks as input. Chickens are entities, so you can't place Chickens with `/fill`. The only way to 'place' entities is to use a spawn egg or `/summon`.